# JSON parsing performance is slow

Tags: java, android

My JSON parser is very slow. I wanted to ask, if I am missing something, or doing something wrong. Is it wrong that I am calling a method in my doInBackground in my AsyncTask, should I put everything in my Asynctask? Every help is appreciated. Here is my relevant code:

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long> {
        private ProgressDialog progress = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(ArticleActivity.this, null,
                    "Artikel wird geladen...");

            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Long doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String link = getIntent().getStringExtra("articleLink");
            getJSONfromURL("my JSON Url");
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
            TextView txtArticle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtViewArticle);
            txtArticle.setText(Html.fromHtml(item.getArticle()));
            progress.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

getJSONfromURL():

```
    public static void getJSONfromURL(String url) {

        // initialize
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";

        // http post
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        // convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
            String myJSON = jObject.getString("content");
            item = new Items();
            item.setArticle(myJSON);
            Log.i("json", myJSON);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

    }
```

Thanks-

Edit:

this is the JSON respnse. It's not that big. I always see these Apps, like google currents, that do not take even a second to load an article. How do they do it?

```
{
    "domain": "www.spiegel.de",
    "next_page_id": null,
    "url": "http://www.spiegel.de/politik/ausland/bloomberg-empfiehlt-obama-als-us-praesident-a-864853.html",
    "short_url": "http://rdd.me/gfvpdlzr",
    "author": null,
    "excerpt": "Washington - Wenige Tage nach dem verheerenden Sturm \"Sandy\" hat der New Yorker Bürgermeister Michael Bloomberg die Wiederwahl von Präsident",
    "direction": "ltr",
    "word_count": 772,
    "total_pages": 0,
    "content": "<div id=\"spArticleColumn\" score=\"62.5\">\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t<div id=\"spArticleTopAsset\" score=\"40.0\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\n<div class=\"spArticleImageBox spAssetAligncenter\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span href=\"http://www.spiegel.de/politik/ausland/bild-864853-420390.html\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<img src=\"http://cdn1.spiegel.de/images/image-420390-panoV9free-jmiw.jpg\" width=\"520\" border=\"0\" class=\"spPanoImageTeaserPic\" title='New Yorks Bürgermeister Bloomberg: \"Unser Klima ändert sich\"' alt='New Yorks Bürgermeister Bloomberg: \"Unser Klima ändert sich\"'></span>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t\t\n</div>\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n<div id=\"spFbTwitterBarStd\" score=\"1.25\">\n\n\t\n\t\t\n\t\n\t\n\n\t\t\t\n\t</div>\n<div id=\"spArticleSection\" score=\"37.5\">\n\t\n<p>Washington - Wenige Tage nach dem verheerenden Sturm \"Sandy\" hat der New Yorker Bürgermeister <a href=\"http://www.spiegel.de/thema/michael_bloomberg/\" title=\"Michael Bloomberg\" class=\"spTextlinkInt\">Michael Bloomberg</a> die Wiederwahl von Präsident <a href=\"http://www.spiegel.de/thema/barack_obama/\" title=\"Barack Obama\" class=\"spTextlinkInt\">Barack Obama</a> empfohlen. Obama habe die Führerschaft beim Thema Klimawandel inne, schrieb das Stadtoberhaupt auf Bloomberg.com.</p>\n\n<p>\n\n\t\"Unser Klima ändert sich. Und während die Zunahme extremer Wetterlagen, die wir in New York und in der Welt erlebt haben, eine Folge davon sind oder nicht sein mögen, das Risiko, das es so sein könnte - angesichts der Zerstörung in dieser Woche - sollte alle gewählten Führer dazu zwingen, sofort zu Handeln\", so der frühere Republikaner Bloomberg. </p>\n\n<p>Die Metropole und die einzelnen US-Staaten könnten solche Katastrophen nicht alleine stemmen: \"Wir brauchen Führung vom Weißen Haus\", schrieb der Bürgermeister. Obama habe in den vergangenen Jahren wichtige Schritte für den Umweltschutz eingeleitet. Romney habe dagegen in allen wichtigen Bereichen einschließlich dem Umweltschutz den Kurs gewechselt.</p>\n\n<p>New York und die gesamte US-Ostküste sind von der Sturmkatastrophe schwer getroffen worden. Bis Donnerstag zählten die Behörden 56 Tote. In Medien ist von über 80 Opfern die Rede. Experten befürchten, dass sich der Schaden, den \"Sandy\" an der US-Ostküste angerichtet hat, auf bis zu 50 Milliarden Dollar summieren könnte. Die Empfehlung für Obama und der Verweis auf extreme Wetterlagen kommen unmittelbar vor dem Urnengang. Am kommenden Dienstag entscheiden die US-Wähler, ob erneut Obama oder sein republikanischer Herausforderer Mitt Romney ins Weiße Haus einzieht.</p>\n\n<div class=\"spPhotoGallery\" score=\"18.25\">\n\t\n\t\t<ul><li class=\"spFirst\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href=\"http://www.spiegel.de/fotostrecke/us-praesident-obama-besucht-sandy-sturm-opfer-in-new-jersey-fotostrecke-89203.html\" title=\"Fotostrecke zeigen...\"><img src=\"http://cdn2.spiegel.de/images/image-419915-thumbbiga-sumg.jpg\" width=\"160\" border=\"0\"></a></li> \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<li>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href=\"http://www.spiegel.de/fotostrecke/us-praesident-obama-besucht-sandy-sturm-opfer-in-new-jersey-fotostrecke-89203.html\" title=\"Fotostrecke zeigen...\"><img src=\"http://cdn2.spiegel.de/images/image-419909-thumbbiga-svrk.jpg\" width=\"160\" border=\"0\"></a></li> \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<li>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href=\"http://www.spiegel.de/fotostrecke/us-praesident-obama-besucht-sandy-sturm-opfer-in-new-jersey-fotostrecke-89203.html\" title=\"Fotostrecke zeigen...\"><img src=\"http://cdn4.spiegel.de/images/image-419877-thumbbiga-dvih.jpg\" width=\"160\" border=\"0\"></a></li> \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</ul><br clear=\"all\">\n\t\t\t<a href=\"http://www.spiegel.de/fotostrecke/us-praesident-obama-besucht-sandy-sturm-opfer-in-new-jersey-fotostrecke-89203.html\" title=\"Fotostrecke zeigen...\"><strong>Obama im Katastrophengebiet:</strong>\n\t\t\t<span>Kümmerer-in-Chief</span></a></div>\n\t<br clear=\"all\">\nDas Krisenmanagement im Nachgang von \"Sandy\" könnte Obama nun vielleicht genau jenen Vorsprung im Präsidentschaftsrennen bringen, den er braucht, um am 6. November zu siegen. Die Wahlempfehlung des beliebten Bloomberg folgt just einen Tag, nachdem der seinerseits beliebte Republikaner und Gouverneur Chris Christie den Präsidenten in seinem Staat New Jersey empfangen, ihn wieder und wieder für seinen Umgang mit der Katastrophe <a href=\"http://www.spiegel.de/politik/ausland/us-praesident-obama-besucht-sandy-sturm-opfer-in-new-jersey-a-864602.html\" title=\"gelobt\" class=\"spTextlinkInt\">gelobt</a> hat: Außerordentlich, exzellent, wunderbar - das waren die Worte Christies, der eigentlich als einer der entschiedensten Unterstützer von Mitt Romney galt. \n\n<p>Dass nun ausgerechnet Regierungschef und Bürgermeister der vom Sturm am schwersten getroffenen Gebiete - New Jersey und New York City - so einhellig die Führungsqualitäten Obamas in der Krise loben, wird Eindruck machen auf viele unabhängige, unentschiedene Wähler. Die zeigten sich in ihrer Mehrheit zunehmend genervt von der polarisierten Auseinandersetzung zwischen Demokraten und Republikanern. Bloomberg selbst wurde zwischenzeitlich gehandelt als aussichtsreicher Dritte-Partei-Kandidat, der sowohl Romney als auch Obama Stimmen hätte nehmen können. Doch er verzichtete. Fortan bemühten sich beide Lager um seine Wahlempfehlung. Obama hat gewonnen.</p>\n\n<p>Obama selbst hat die Hilfsbereitschaft für die Opfer des Hurrikans \"Sandy\" gelobt. Die Nachbarschaftshilfe sei ebenso überragend gewesen wie die Hilfe über die Parteigrenzen hinweg, sagte Obama am Donnerstag bei einem Wahlkampfauftritt in Green Bay im Bundesstaat Wisconsin. \"Während eines Sturms gibt es keine Demokraten und keine Republikaner\", erklärte der Präsident. Er appellierte an die US-Bürger, die Sturmopfer weiter zu unterstützen. \"Wir sind sprachlos und demütigt angesichts der zerstörerischen Kraft der Natur\", sagte Obama bei seinem ersten Wahlkampfauftritt nach einer Hurrikan-bedingten Zwangspause. </p>\n\n<p>\n<b>Obama setzt erneut auf \"Change\"-Slogan</b>\n</p>\n\n<p>Unterdessen belebt Obama im Wahlkampf-Endspurt einen seiner erfolgreichen Slogans von 2008 wieder: \"Change\". \"Ich weiß wie Wandel aussieht, denn ich habe dafür gekämpft\", sagte er vor etwa 2600 Zuhörern im Bundesstaat Wisconsin. Sein Herausforderer Mitt Romney wolle die Wirtschaftskrise mit Mitteln lösen, die Ursache der ökonomischen Probleme seien, die er bei seinem Amtsantritt vorgefunden habe, sagte Obama. </p>\n\n<p>\"Romney hat alle seine Talente als Verkäufer genutzt, um genau die Politik aufzuhübschen, die unserem Land so sehr geschadet hat. Es ist dieselbe Politik, hinter der wir in den vergangenen vier Jahren hergeputzt haben - und das bietet er an als Wandel.\" So aber sehe Wandel - \"change\" - nicht aus.</p>\n\n<p>\n\n\t\"Change\" war neben \"Hope\" - Hoffnung - einer der Schlüsselbegriffe, mit denen Obama 2008 das Weiße Haus eroberte. Doch im laufenden Wahlkampf verzichtete er bislang weitgehend darauf, an diese griffigen Slogans anzuknüpfen - wohl auch, weil ihm viele Wähler vorwerfen, zu wenig in Washington bewegt und viele seiner Ankündigungen von vor vier Jahren nicht umgesetzt zu haben. </p>\n\n<p>Statt dessen zog Romney mit dem Versprechen durchs Land, für \"wahren Wandel\" - \"real change\" zu sorgen, sollte er am kommenden Dienstag zum Präsidenten gewählt werden. Fünf Tage vor der Wahl schien Obama nun entschlossen, den Begriff für sich zurückzuerobern. \"Wisconsin, ich sage Euch: Wir wissen, wie Wandel aussieht. Und was Romney anbietet, ist sicher kein Wandel.\" </p>\n\n<p>Wisconsin ist einer jener Handvoll Staaten, die die Wahl mitentscheiden könnten, denn hier ist noch nicht klar, wer von den beiden Bewerbern am Ende die Nase vorn haben wird. Auch Nevada, Colorado und Ohio zählen zu den \"battleground states\", die zum Zünglein an der Waage werden könnten. Auch sie standen auf dem Reiseplan des Präsidenten am Donnerstag. Romney wird am Freitag in Wisconsin und Ohio erwartet.</p>\n\n</div>\n<p><i>lei/dpa</i></p>\n\t\n\t\t\n\n\n<br class=\"spBreakNoHeight\" clear=\"all\"></div>\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t",
    "date_published": "2012-11-01 20:02:00",
    "dek": "Barack Obama punktet mit seinem Krisenmanagement nach der \"Sandy\"-Katastrophe. New Yorks Bürgermeister Bloomberg setzt sich für die Wiederwahl des US-Präsidenten ein - und verweist auf dessen Klimapolitik. Zuvor hatte ihn bereits ein Top-Wahlhelfer von Mitt Romney gelobt.",
    "lead_image_url": "http://cdn1.spiegel.de/images/image-420390-thumb-jmiw.jpg",
    "title": "US-Wahlkampf: New Yorks Bürgermeister empfiehlt Obama",
    "rendered_pages": 1
}
```

Comment: I suspect your connection is just taking a while to load the data. What type of connection are you on? Emulator or device? And what exactly is "slow"?

Comment: How about timing how long is spent loading the data versus how long is spent parsing it? How large are these objects, anyway?

Comment: I tried with emulator and real device. I have a 32 mb/s bandwith, so that shouldn't be the problem. Wait a minute I'll put up the JSON response :)

Comment: One micro-optimisation would be to ditch the `\n` in `sb.append(line + "\n");`- I don't think you should need it, and it currently creates an extra StringBuilder behind the scenes to join the `line` and the `\n`. I don't believe this will make a measurable difference with data that small though.

Comment: Did you breakpoint on either side of the JSON part to make sure that's the trouble? easier to isolate that way - most JSON parsing patterns I've seen look pretty much like yours

Comment: @JRaymond sorry I don't I understand what you mean by breakpoint :/

Comment: @user1330645 Don't know what it would be in german, but halt code execution before you make your request, before you parse JSON, and after you parse JSON - then you can observe empirically how long the download takes and how long the JSON takes

Comment: ah ok :) - I will try timing it and update the question

Comment: Just a fyi, the whole "let's create a bunch of readers & read the content line by line" - don't do that, use [EntityUtils#toString(..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do find that the JSON parser is taking a significant amount of time I would reccomend switching to the [Jackson Streaming API](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonStreamingApi). It requires a bit more work to setup than other parsers, but I've found it to be extremely fast.

Comment: Jackson is lightning fast. Use it!